# Google Maps Animate Placemark Using KML

Tags: google-maps, kml

I have a html file with a Google Map view embedded, and I'm using JavaScript to load a separate kml file's data into the Google Map. In the KML file, I have the latitude/longitude coordinates of a car's route, and I've used the LineString function to connect the coordinates into a single line. I'm wondering how to now animate a placemark on the LineString drawn by my given coordinates.

I've looked at [this](http://www.kmcgraphics.com/google/) example, and it's sort of what I'm trying to do, but the example doesn't use a KML file. [This](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html#gxtrack) example will animate a route given by latitude and longitude coordinates, but the command `gx:track` is only supported by Google Earth, and not Google Maps, according to my own testing and [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/WDfrSC5GKRc) thread.

**Essentially, I'm trying to animate a placemark through predetermined coordinates on a web-based Google Maps interface.** Here's some of my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="2.2.xsd">
<Document>
<Placemark id="car">
 <name>Initial position of car</name>
 <description>Latitude: 31.2844 Longitude: 121.436</description>
 <Point>
 <coordinates>121.436,31.2844</coordinates>
 </Point>
 </Placemark>
<Placemark><LineString><coordinates>
121.436,31.2844,0 
121.435,31.2857,0 
121.435,31.2863,0 
...more coordinates here...
</coordinates></LineString></Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

How would I move the placemark with id of "car" along the linestring?

Comment: [Example of animating a marker along a polyline from KML (using geoxml3)](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_animateMarker_linkto.html?lat=-39.474537&lng=-62.500301&zoom=13&type=m&filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/julieta.kml) - [second example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_animateMarker_linkto.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/JBU181_20110102_kml.xml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load your placemarks / lines from KML but in google maps you cannot define an animation (like a tour). To accomplish what you are asking you have to manipulate the map using the JavaScript API based on the contents of your KML file. That is - the example you posted is a great start point.

Also - I am working on something similar to this now (will be part of a deliverable due sometime over the next month - two). If you beat me to completing it you should post back with any lessons learned.

Comment: Thanks, I figured as much seeing that I found almost nothing related to what I was looking for on Google. I'm currently reading up on the JavaScript API and I'm wondering if I will have to scratch my current KML file completely and redo the whole code using JavaScript? Or is there a way for the JavaScript and the KML to interact?

Comment: And yes, I will keep updating this as I make progress.

Comment: You can parse the KML in your JavaScript like you would any XML document. Create an array of your coordinates and then in a loop with a slight delay move your placemark, center the map,  and refresh it. Try this to parse: http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/